# Remove everything else other than digits upon paste in input area

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

When I paste let's say 222-222-2222, into the input area, I get - 22222222 - I get 8 characters rather than 10 because of the spaces in between. I would like it so when the user pastes a number, all digits are accounted for. And the space/other characters have been removed like it is currently. The user cannot currently target the input area and enter in other characters other than digits but unsure of how to account for the paste action. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lj82e5y/3/)

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" style="width: 210px;" maxlength="10" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var y = function(e) {


  var target = e.target;
  var position = target.selectionStart;

  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  var value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + x[2] + (x[3] ? x[3] : '');
  if (value === e.target.value) {
    return;
  }
  e.target.value = value;
  var last = x[3];
  target.selectionEnd = position; // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
};
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', y);

//In order to avoid jumb behavious when press non-numeric like a-z
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: It might not hurt to make that input a number type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On paste, change the input's maxlength to a large value:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  this.maxLength = 999;
});
```

At the end of the input event, restore it to 10:

```
var y = function(e) {
  ...
  this.maxLength = 10;
};
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmoojk9L/)**